# riemann email setup issue

Tags: clojure, riemann

I am trying to set up riemann (for monitoring) with email alerts.  I have used the following section in my riemann.config file but after reloading the config, I get the error copied below.  Any thoughts on troubleshooting this will be greatly appreciated.

**Riemann.config**

```
(streams
 (where (and (service #"^riemann netty execution-handler")
             (state "critical"))
        (email "user@somewhere.com")))
```

**Error**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: email in this context, compiling:(/home/user/test/riemann-0.2.4/etc/riemann.config:40:9)
```

I forgot to add the mailer section in the config - update to follow.

The attempt to send the email is successful - I am getting a different error now which I will post as a separate question ([riemann email exception with SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075384/riemann-email-exception-with-smtp)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `(let ...)` expression that defines `email` as a `mailer`.

See example [HERE](http://riemann.io/howto.html#send-email)

Comment: yes - I observed the same and got this to work.  Thank you for sharing.